# Bootstrap Datepicker - Change days of week abbreviation within pop-up

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins, datepicker

I'm using the datepicker plugin from https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker

Without changing the library itself, is there any way to change the abbreviation formatting of the days of the week within the calendar pop-up?

I'm hoping it's an option I can pass as I'd like to use DaysShort instead of DaysMin.

Screenshot of the area I'm trying to adjust: http://take.ms/qJvdA

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the language property to change the location, and modify the abbreviation as you want, for example using this reference:

https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/blob/master/js/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.es.js

```
$(function($){
    $.fn.datepicker.dates['es'] = {
        days: ["Domingo", "Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado", "Domingo"],
        daysShort: ["Dom", "Lun", "Mar", "Mié", "Jue", "Vie", "Sáb", "Dom"],
        daysMin: ["Do", "Lu", "Ma", "Mi", "Ju", "Vi", "Sa", "Do"],
        months: ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"],
        monthsShort: ["Ene", "Feb", "Mar", "Abr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dic"],
        today: "Hoy"
    };
});

$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    language: "es"
});
```

Here is an example of how you can edit the properties

http://jsfiddle.net/2LS3S/

In this [link](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/tree/master/js/locales) you there are more locales js

Comment: Thank you for replying. What I'm hoping to avoid is having to modify the library like this (http://jsfiddle.net/K8qwL/1/) to get the calendar to show the daysShort values for the days of the week when displaying the calendar.

Comment: I didn't want to have to change the library but in the case of this plug-in and the application I was working on, it was the solution I went with. :)

Answer (score 0):

Was unable to find an answer that used any of the plugin's available options. I ended up changing the library itself so that the daysShort array held the same values as daysMin.